# Is it possible to detect changes of sensor data while app is running in background (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm currently learning react-native and I try to set the screen brightness depending whether your eyes are open or closed with the camera on Android.
This works well when the app is running, but now I try to achieve the same thing when the app runs in background.

I tried to solve it by using the `expo-background-fetch` and `expo-task-manager` packages.
I defined a background task which should get the updated data and decide to update or not update the screen brightness.
Unfortunately I always get this error message as soon as I close the app (runs in background).

```
TaskManager: Task "backgroundTaskName" failed:, [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.faces.length')]
```

I need to detect changes on the FaceDetector while the app is closed and update the screen brightness.

This is my code from App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Camera} from 'expo-camera';
import * as FaceDetector from 'expo-face-detector';
import * as Brightness from 'expo-brightness';
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';


let eyeProbabilityFn = () => {};

async function backgroundTask(data) {

    if (data.faces.length === 0) {
        return BackgroundFetch.Result.NoData;
    }

    if (data.faces[0].leftEyeOpenProbability < eyeProbabilityFn || 
        data.faces[0].rightEyeOpenProbability < eyeProbabilityFn) {
        return BackgroundFetch.Result.NewData;
    } else {
        return BackgroundFetch.Result.NoData;
    }
}

async function initBackgroundFetch(taskName,
                                   taskFn,
                                   interval = 60 * 15) {
    try {
        if (!TaskManager.isTaskDefined(taskName)) {
            TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, taskFn);
        }
        const options = {
            minimumInterval: interval // in seconds
        };
        await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(taskName, options);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("registerTaskAsync() failed:", err);
    }
}

initBackgroundFetch('backgroundTaskName', backgroundTask, 3);


const App = () => {

    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.front);
    const [eyeProbability, setEyeProbability] = useState(0.8);

    eyeProbabilityFn = eyeProbability;

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const cameraStatus = (await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()).status;
            setHasPermission(cameraStatus === 'granted');

            const brightnessStatus = (await Brightness.requestPermissionsAsync()).status;
            if (brightnessStatus === 'granted') {
            }

        })();
    }, []);

    if (hasPermission === null) {
        return <View/>;
    }
    if (hasPermission === false) {
        return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }

    const handleFacesDetected = async (data) => {
        if (data.faces.length === 0) {
            await Brightness.useSystemBrightnessAsync();
            return;
        }

        if (data.faces[0].leftEyeOpenProbability < eyeProbability || data.faces[0].rightEyeOpenProbability < eyeProbability) {
            await Brightness.setBrightnessAsync(0.3);
        } else {
            await Brightness.useSystemBrightnessAsync();
        }
        await backgroundTask(data);

    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera
                ratio={'16:9'}
                style={styles.camera}
                type={type}
                onFacesDetected={handleFacesDetected}
                faceDetectorSettings={{
                    mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.fast,
                    detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.none,
                    runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.all,
                    minDetectionInterval: 1000,
                    tracking: true,
                }}>

                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={() => {
                            setType(
                                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                                    ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                                    : Camera.Constants.Type.back
                            );
                        }}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}> Flip </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Camera>
        </View>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Can someone give me a hint how to pass the Facedetector data to my background task?